# How to count attributes of a nested model

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm building an app with Express, Postgres for DB and Sequelize for ORM.

I have 4 models:
`User`, who has many `Post`s and many `Topics`
`Posts`, belongs to `User` and has many `Topics` through `PostTopic`
`Topic`, belongs to `User` and `Post` through `PostTopic`
`PostTopic` belongs to `Post` and `Topic`

This is the response I get:

```js
"users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-04-16T22:52:59.054Z",
        "post": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "post_topic": [
             {topic_id: 1},
             {topic_id: 2}
             ]
          },
          {
            "id": 2
            "post_topic": [
             {topic_id: 3},
             {topic_id: 4},
             {topic_id: 5}
             ]
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
```

I want to get the number of topics for each post.

```js
      User.findOne({
        where: { id: req.params.id },
        include: [
          { model: Post,
            include: {
              model: PostTopic
            }
          }
        ]
      })
```

I know there is a `COUNT` method by postgres but I can't make it work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ,

```
User.findAll({
        where: { id: req.params.id },
        attributes : [ 'user.*' , sequelize.fn('count', db.sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', db.sequelize.col('user_posts.id'))) ]
        include: [
          { 
              model: UserPost,
              attributes : [] // <------- Note this --------
          }
        ],
        group :[''user.id','user_posts.id'] // <--- Change name as per your table name
      })
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I didn't structure my question correctly. I updated it. I tried to run your code but it gave me error `invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "post_topic"`